# Solving for Fisher Kolmagorov Partial Differential Equation

Tags: matlab, pde

I have been trying to solve the non dimensional Fisher Kolmagorov equation in Matlab. I am getting a graph which doesn't look at all like it should. Also, I'm getting the equation independent of value of `s` (the source term in the `pdepe` solver). No matter what value of `s` I put in the graph remains the same.

```
function FK     
m = 0;    
x = linspace(0,1,100);    
t = linspace(0,1,100);    
u = pdepe(m,@FKpde,@FKic,@FKbc,x,t);    
[X,T] = meshgrid(x,t);

%ANALYTICAL SOLUTION    
% a=(sqrt(2))-1;    
% q=2;    
% s=2/q;    
% b= q /((2*(q+2))^0.5);    
% c= (q+4)/((2*(q+2))^0.5);    
% zeta= X-c*T;    
%y = 1/((1+(a*(exp(b*zeta))))^s);    
%r=(y(:,:)-u(:,:))./y(:,:); % relative error in numerical and analytical value

figure;    
plot(x,u(10,:),'o',x,u(40,:),'o',x,u(60,:),'o',x,u(end,:),'o')    
title('Numerical Solutions at different times');    
legend('tn=1','tn=5','tn=30','tn=10','ta=20','ta=600','ta=800','ta=1000',0);    
xlabel('Distance x');
ylabel('u(x,t)');    

% --------------------------------------------------------------------------
function [c,f,s] = FKpde(x,t,u,DuDx)    
c = 1;    
f = DuDx;    
s =u*(1-u);

% --------------------------------------------------------------------------    
function u0 = FKic(x)    
u0 = 10^(-4);

% --------------------------------------------------------------------------    
function [pl,ql,pr,qr] = FKbc(xl,ul,xr,ur,t)    
pl = ul-1;    
ql = 0;    
pr = ur;    
qr = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Should maybe be a comment, but putting it as an answer for better formatting.  Your analytic solution, which I assume you're using to compare with the numerical answer to say that the graph does not look as it should, does not appear to respect the initial conditions or boundary conditions you are feeding pdepe, so I'd start there if trying to figure out why `u` does not look like `y`

The initial and boundary conditions you are setting are:

```
u(0, t) = 1
u(1, t) = 0
u(x, 0) = 1e-4
```

Setting aside that the boundary and initial conditions are in conflict, the analytic solution you suggest in the code has

```
u(0, t) = 1/((1+exp(-b*ct)))
u(1, t) = 1/((1+exp(b*(1-ct)))
u(x, 0) = 1/((1+exp(b*x))
```

So it seems to me the numerical and analytic solutions should be expected to be different, and the differences you observe are probably due to the IC/BC setup.  I suspect that `pdepe` is probably solving the equation you are giving it.

Comment: I know the analytic solution wrong. I have commented it. (I knew I should have removed it, sorry!) The pdepe graph looks exactly the same no matter what source term you give it. Thats why i was wondering if something was wrong with the pdepe.

Comment: I disagree that the solution does not depend on the source term - I changed the source term from u*(1-u) to 1e3*u*(1-u) and get very different graphs.

Answer (score 0):

On increasing the length scale and time scale, I get the answers I want. The problem was to solve for different times, and see the wave propogate. For small lenghts, I could only see part of that wave.